# Bootstrap 4 - Two buttons with Dropdown - second button show first button's content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have added 2 buttons (Bootstrap 4) with Dropdown functionality.

The first button shows its content properly.
The second button shows the content of the 1st button!

I have created a jsfiddle to reproduce the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/marcvidalmoreno/8061s2ca/

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm mr-1 dropdown-toggle"
        id="button1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Button 1
</button>

<div aria-labelledby="button1" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm mr-1 dropdown-toggle"
        id="button2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Button 2
</button>

<div aria-labelledby="button2" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cross Cutting Activities</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

The button and the dropdown-menu container need to be wrapped by a div with the class btn-group:

https://jsfiddle.net/marcvidalmoreno/vyLapn6j/1/

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm mr-1 dropdown-toggle"
          id="button1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Button 1
  </button>
  <div aria-labelledby="button1"
       class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
      Item 1
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
      Item 2
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm mr-1 dropdown-toggle"
          id="button2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Button 2
  </button>
  <div aria-labelledby="button2"
       class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
      Item 3
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or `.dropdown`, see the official docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#single-button